# html python same value in 2 many to many

Tags: python, html, django, many-to-many

this is a rather simple but yet strange question.

I have 2 ManyToMany relationships in a table pointing to the same other table (I need this so I can know who participated in an event and who finished it)

In my html I have a table, and I want a field to know if someone just was there and who finished the event.

The backend sending the data to my html is something like this:

```
for e in ev.event.all():
  people.append(e)
return render_to_response('event/review.html', {'event': people}, 
context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In my html I've tried this:

```
{% for p in event %}
  {% if p.asistant in p.finish %}
    <td>Finish</td>
  {% else %}
    <td>
      <form action="{% url .....
```

But nothing happens.

What I'm doing wrong?

My models is something like this:

```
class Event(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
  date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
  asistant = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='asistant_to_event', blank=True, null=True)
  finish = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='finished_the_event', blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: you know you can structure the m2m table to have a boolean-field that could track is_finisher or not. check here [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#many-to-one-relationships)

Comment: what i am trying to say is create a model class Participants (event(fk), user(fk), is_finisher(bool)).. 
in your class Event remove (assistant and finish) and add participants = models.m2mField(User, through='Participants', related_name='participants' blank=True, null=true)